# Execute some code only once for bank wire confirmed payment in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

**For the bank transfer (bacs) payment method**, since the store manager manually confirms that the order is paid by changing the order status, you need to use the special `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hook.

The status of successful orders can be changed from

1. On Hold to Processing,
2. On Hold to Completed, or
3. On Hold to Processing to Completed.

**However, the action should only be fired once for each successful order.**

---

I tried to achieve this by checking the payment date of the orders `&& ! $order->get_date_paid('edit')`, but it seems not to be a working solution because a payment date is always received.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'bacs_payment_complete', 10, 4 );
function bacs_payment_complete( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
  // 1. For Bank wire and cheque payments
  if( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), array('bacs') 
  && in_array( $new_status, array('processing', 'completed') 
  && ! $order->get_date_paid('edit') ) {
    // Do something
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get some code executed just once in this function, you need to tag the order like:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'bacs_payment_complete', 10, 4 );
function bacs_payment_complete( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
    // 1. For Bank wire and cheque payments
    if ( $order->get_payment_method() === 'bacs' 
    && in_array( $new_status, wc_get_is_paid_statuses() )
    && $order->get_meta('confirmed_paid') !== 'yes' ) 
    {
        $order->update_meta_data('confirmed_paid', 'yes'); // Tag the order
        $order->save(); // Save to database

        // Here the code to be executed only once
    } 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.